# Is it possible to use a view as a field in another view?

Tags: views

I have two views. First one is an unformatted view from a content type, and second one is a table view of most viewed from the same content type. Now I want to show both of these views in a page without using panel module. Is there any way to attach these views?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question and the body of your question seem different to me.

To use the results of a view as a field in another view, you would use [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

To display two views at the same time, make one a page display and the other an attachment display attached to the page display.

Comment: I have problem with both ways. when I use Views Field View, the table view show completely in my boxes. and when I add an attachment, if I set its format as Table, my Page display also change to Table, and when I set my page format to Unformatted, it affects on attachment display, But I need to different format here. What should I do to separate their Format style?

Comment: o! With setting display just for page and attachment I could make them to show different!